# Cannot apply any Bootstrap style in using React-bootstrap library

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

I want to use default Bootstrap components in my React application, so I'm using React-bootstrap NPM-package. But I stuck at the very beginning: I cannot use any [default component](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html) although I'm just copying very simple exmaples from official docs. Every time I use Bootstrap-styled component, I get basic component withouts styles. For example the code below renders a `<button>` without styles, not `<Button bsStyle="danger">` from Bootstrap.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from "./store";
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Button bsStyle="danger">Danger</Button>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

Why do I have such a problem? Maybe it's about Babel or Webpack: some styles are being ignored during the packaging?

Comment: Did you import bootstrap css?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I didn't include Bootstrap CSS `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: so that is solved?

Comment: @LucasKatayama Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use react-bootstrap component you need use the bootstrap-css in your code in order to encorporate the styles.

You can do this by adding the follwowing in your index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=""https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

From the react-bootstrap docs

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of
>   Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included css. However, some
>   stylesheet is required to use these components. How and which
>   bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the simplest way is to
>   include the latest styles from the CDN.

[**DOCS**](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html)

Comment: But this is somehow strange. Because I'm using packager, in my `index.html` I include just one style: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>`, although I wrote a lot of `.css` files. Why are Bootstrap styles not included in package?

Comment: Which packager do you use. As of I know, I include all the css files that I write and the other way would be specify a css-loader in webpack and with that we can require the relevant file in the required component

Comment: I'm using Webpack and Babel.