# Import jquery and bootstrap in reactjs as ES6

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

When i try to use jquery and bootstrap. I received the below error

```
Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
```

Find the below order which i am using.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import jquery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery=jquery;
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, Glyphicon, MenuItem, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Please help me to import bootstrap and jquery in reactjs

Comment: You shouln't use Jquery with React, If you want to make use of react-bootstrap, you don't actually need jquery but only Bootstrap css

Comment: Can you help me how to do that. I have make changes by removing jquery but still bootstrap classes are not getting affected.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784226/cannot-apply-any-bootstrap-style-in-using-react-bootstrap-library/40784883#40784883

Answer (score 0):

Move the jQuery window assignment below the react-bootstrap import. As someone already mentioned, you don't need to import your own jQuery to use react-bootstrap. Have a look at their [installation instructions](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html) and you'll see that the only required deps are `react` and `react-dom`.

Comment: Can you give me one sample please.

Comment: Yeah, I posted a link to their docs with lots of examples. Check it here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html