# React Bootstrap Modal appears under the rest of the content instead of overlay.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hello i am trying to use the Reat Bootstrap Modal it works fine in the way that it appears and everything the problem is that it appears at the bottom under all the other content and not ontop of it as it supposed to work

[image]

as you can see at the marked area that is my modal that appears when you click the button but for some reason it appers under everything.

here is how it renders

```
<div>
   <label><b>Dina uppgifter</b></label>
   <br />
   <input type="text" placeholder="Namn eller användar-id" value={this.state.userId} onChange={this.setUserId} />
   </div>
   <Backup onSelectedDatabase={this.handleDatabaseSelected} onSelectedCustomer={this.handleCustomerSelected}/>
   <Version onSelectedVersion={this.handleVersionChange}/>
   <div>
   <label><b>Namn på Oystern</b></label>
   <br />
   <input onFocus= {this.oysterNameFocus} type="text" placeholder="Ange namn" value={this.state.oysterName} onChange={this.setOysterName}/>
   <p className="SmallText">Tillåtna tecken är A-Z, a-z och 0-9</p>
   </div>
   <div>
   <Button onClick={this.handleClickOyster}> Skapa oyster</Button>
   </div>
   <div>
   <Modal show={this.state.dbExistModal} onHide={() => this.setState({dbExistModal:false})}>
   <Modal.Title>Database already exsists. Are you sure you want to overwrite it?</Modal.Title>
   <Modal.Footer>
   <button onClick={this.createOyster}>Yes</button>
   <button onClick={() => this.setState({dbExistModal:false})}>No</button>
   </Modal.Footer>
   </Modal>
   </div>
   </div>
```

At the bottom there you see the Modal it doesnt matter if i put it at the top of the render it always appears at the bottom. anyone who sees why it doesnt appear ontop instead?

Comment: did you include css for react-bootstrap

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784226/cannot-apply-any-bootstrap-style-in-using-react-bootstrap-library/40784883#40784883

Comment: it looks like you need to ref the css style sheet: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Yeah that were it! totally forgot to add the link! Thank you guys i have been googling my ass of for while trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

import css file in your app root file

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```